# Why does my network stop working when adding a second IP to a second NIC in netplan and starting a docker container exposed on that nic's IP?

Tags: networking, docker, netplan, nginx

"Stop working" might be an overstatement, but parts of it do, and I don't know enough about what's happening to phrase it shorter for a title.

Basically, I have

- A machine with 2 nic srunning one VM and a bunch of Docker containers. NIC#1 has IP `10.0.30.21` and NIC#2 was recenlty set up and assigned `10.0.30.22`.

  - One VM running Home Assistant OS (IP: `10.0.30.61:8123`, and served by NGINX at `hass.my_domain.tld`)
  - A bunch of Docker containers, incl. of (potential) interest:

    - NGINX (linuxserver/swag) (using ports `80` and `443`)
    - deCONZ (using ports `8080` and `8443`)
    - Z-WaveJS2MQTT Server (using port `8091` and `3000`)

All docker containers of interest expose ports on `10.0.30.21`.

Until now, I have only used the one nic, but for unrelated reasons, I want to move my unifi controller to a docker container. Since it uses some ports already in use on the `10.0.30.21` IP (e.g. the ones used by deCONZ), I wanted to set up the second NIC and use a different IP.

So, I added the second interface to my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:            # <-- These two lines are what I added
      dhcp4: true    # <-- These two lines are what I added
  version: 2
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
             - eno1
      parameters:
        stp: true
```

It seems at first to work fine, the new mac shows up and I can assign IP and all that in the dhcp server.

For the unifi controller, I used the port bindings that should tie everything to the "new" `10.0.30.22` IP (from the unifi-controller section in my `docker-compose`):

```
    ports:
      - 10.0.30.22:8443:8443
      - 10.0.30.22:3478:3478/udp
      - 10.0.30.22:10001:10001/udp
      - 10.0.30.22:8080:8080
      - 10.0.30.22:1900:1900/udp #optional
      - 10.0.30.22:8843:8843 #optional
      - 10.0.30.22:8880:8880 #optional
      - 10.0.30.22:6789:6789 #optional
      - 10.0.30.22:5514:5514/udp #optional
```

##### But when I then start the unifi-controller docker container (linuxserver/unifi-controller), a few things happen:

1. The Home Assistant VM can no longer access deCONZ or Z-waveJS2MQTT services

   - The error logs just say that they are not available at their IP (`10.0.30.21`)
   - I can still access both of their web UIs at local IP:port (`10.0.30.21:8080` and `10.0.30.21:8091`), and I can control devices through this web UI (so it seems fully functional)
2. The Home Assistant VM web UI is no longer accessible at `hass.my_domain.tld` **despite**:

   - The web UI being reachable and functional at the local IP (`10.0.30.61:8123`)
   - No errors or warnings in NGINX logs
   - No errors or warnings in Home Assistant logs
   - Maybe errors in `docker logs deconz`, I'm not sure if related.

     - deCONS: `Unbind response failed with status 0x88 for 0x84fd27fffe70d3ed ep: 0x01 cluster: 0x2000`
3. I did not loose FQDN access to **any other services** served by NGINX, which include both services on that machine, and on other machines, e.g.:

   - Nextcloud (local IP `10.0.30.67`)
   - DokuWiki (local IP `10.0.30.21`)
   - TrueNAS (local IP `10.0.30.27`)
   - PiHole (local IP `10.0.30.43`)
   - etc.

When I then kill the unifi-controller, **noting changes**, there's still no access. When I remove the unifi-controller section from my docker-compose, and completely reboot the system, **nothing change**. Still no access.

The only way I could restore was the remove the `eno2` lines from the netplan file, then reboot, and everything came back as before.

What on earth am I doing wrong here?

(Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using. Please add it to the question not in a comment.

Comment: Sure, added to the above.

Comment: Two DHCP entries will result in changing network gateways which breaks your internet.  Whichever DHCP entry is *second* will result in that being your default Internet route and break your network access to the Internet, etc. because of dual DHCP.  At least *one* of those interfaces needs to be static and not set as the default route.

Comment: So it would be enough simply to change the `eno2` lines above to `dhcp: false` and add and `addresses: ` key with e.g. `- 10.0.30.22/24` (he asked, afraid to try due to the fury of family with network trouble)?